# jquery + open hidden DIV by choosing option and send form value

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select

I have apply form, working with jquery & php mail, but can't workout one last problem, here is select options:

```
<select name="LV01S01F001" id="LV01S01F001" class="selectform">`
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">choose one</option>
<option value="ID001">01 - option name + short description</option>
<option value="ID002">02 - option name + short description</option>
<option value="ID003">03 - option name + short description</option>
</select>
```

So by selected option, using it's value it opens hidden DIV, using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#LV01S01F001').change(function(){
            $('.CREDITDIV').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Poinf of problem, that script is using *select option value*, same time *value* is sended by *php mail*, but i need to send it's text, but not it's value, so make it look like:

```
<option>01 - option name + short description</option>
```

So it would send **01 - option name + short description**, but not **ID001** as it's value.

Or change **value**

```
<option value="ID003">
```

to some thing else?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj447/)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try with **.text()** like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#LV01S01F001').change(function(){
            $('.CREDITDIV').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
     });
</script>
```

But better to use its values only,not the texts that we have selected.See this [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj447/1/)

Comment: I know, but i have to send option text to email, not it's value ID. So using **.text()** how would look **<option value="ID001">01 - option name + short description</option>** and hidden DIV? **<div id="ID001" class="CREDITDIV" style="display:none">** ?

Comment: Do one thing.just fiddle it,I will tell you

Comment: got it, but i mean, bit different thing, this edit it send **value** to email, and shows option text in hidden DIV.
But there are few more inputs in hidden DIV, so i can't put HTML to value, practicly i need to send form it's text to email and open hidden DIV without using **value** & **val** tags

Comment: Not value ,it will send text

Comment: Check this, [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj447/3/) here is how it works, so is there a chance to send **option text** to email and open hidden div by some other tag, without using **value* or and **val** tag?

Answer (score 0):

To get the **text** of the **selected option** use:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Where `this` refers to the `<select>`

For example:

```
$('.selectform').change(function() {
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm not so good at js, so how would hidden DIV looks like than?